# Two input appended by jquery does not align on the same line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a form page where the user must insert at least two fields: name and price. So I managed that with a div containing a label (for the field name) and an input item (for the field value).

**Field name and field value must be on the same line.**

Field name must be on the left, in a limited-width div, while field value must be on the right and expand on all the line.
The user must have the ability to add fields by clicking on a plus button.

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="product-attributes">
    <div class="product-attribute">
        <label class="field-name">Name</label><input class="field-value" type="text" name="name">
    </div>
    <div class="product-attribute">
        <label class="field-name">Price</label><input class="field-value" type="text" name="price">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="product-attribute-add">
    <label class="product-attribute-add-label">+</label>
</div>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
.product-attributes {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.product-attribute {
    display:table;
    width:100%
}

label,
.field-name {
    display:table-cell;
    margin: 0;
}

.product-attribute .field-name {
    width: 80px;
}

.product-attribute-add-label {
    margin: 0;
}

.field-value,
input[type="submit"] {
    display:table-cell;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0; ...
}
```

[image: Before clicking of the plus]

When the user clicks on the plus label I append a new div with:

```
addField = function() {
    var attributeName = 'NEW';
    $(this).parent().siblings('.product-attributes').append(
        '<div class="product-attribute">'
        + '<input class="field-name" type="text" value="' + attributeName.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + attributeName.slice(1) + '"/>'
        + '<input class="field-value" type="text" name="' + attributeName + '"/>'
        + '</div>'
        );
}
$('label.product-attribute-add-label').click(addField);
```

[image: After clicking on the plus]

Why are they not on the same line? I tried everything but I can't do this. If I switch the first input inside a dive with a label they are on the same line but i can't do this with two inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using flexbox than CSS table.

```
.product-attribute {
  display: flex;
}

.field-name {
  flex: 0 0 80px;
  max-width: 80px;
}

.field-value {
  flex: 1;
}
```

**Snippet**

```js
addField = function() {
  var attributeName = 'NEW';
  $(this).parent().siblings('.product-attributes').append(
    '<div class="product-attribute">' + '<input class="field-name" type="text" value="' + attributeName.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + attributeName.slice(1) + '"/>' + '<input class="field-value" type="text" name="' + attributeName + '"/>' + '</div>'
  );
}
$('label.product-attribute-add-label').click(addField);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.product-attribute {
  display: flex;
}

.field-name {
  flex: 0 0 80px;
  max-width: 80px;
}

.field-value {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-attributes">
  <div class="product-attribute">
    <label class="field-name">Name</label>
    <input class="field-value" type="text" name="name">
  </div>
  <div class="product-attribute">
    <label class="field-name">Price</label>
    <input class="field-value" type="text" name="price">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="product-attribute-add">
  <label class="product-attribute-add-label">+</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem stems from the browser adding styles to `input` by default - `padding`, `border`, `font` ...

You can place the elements on the same row using `display: flex` on the parent container, and align them using `width` and `margin-right`.

For accuracy, the `input` needs a small `width` adjustment to account for its border.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/ey7eL96g/2/)

```js
addField = function() {
  var attributeName = 'New';
  $(this).parent().siblings('.product-attributes').append(
    '<div class="product-attribute">' + '<input class="field-name" type="text" value="' + attributeName.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + attributeName.slice(1) + '"/>' + '<input class="field-value" type="text" name="' + attributeName + '"/>' + '</div>'
  );
}
$('label.product-attribute-add-label').click(addField);
```

```css
.product-attribute {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-bottom: .45em;
}

label,
.field-name {
  margin: 0;
}

.product-attribute .field-name {
  min-width: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

.product-attribute-add-label {
  margin: 0;
}

.field-value,
input[type="submit"] {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

/* account for the border added to input by defaul */
.product-attribute input.field-name {
  margin-right: calc(1em - 1px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-attributes">
  <div class="product-attribute">
    <label class="field-name">Name</label>
    <input class="field-value" type="text" name="name">
  </div>
  <div class="product-attribute">
    <label class="field-name">Price</label>
    <input class="field-value" type="text" name="price">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="product-attribute-add">
  <label class="product-attribute-add-label">+</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The CSS scaffolding is incorrect, you probably want

```
product-attributes -> display: table
```

and

```
product-attribute -> display: table-cell
```

As now, product-attribute is a table with 100% width.

Comment: No, I want a row or a table for each couple product-attribute. That it's not important for me but It's important that the second input starts when the first ends and then expands on all the row.